# Returning a decyphered string as part of tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell, encryption, xor

For project euler 59, I came up with this to return a list of tuples containing the decyphered string and the key used (and yes I know about `Data.Bits`):

```
module XOR where
import Data.List
import Data.Char
decToBin :: Integer -> [Integer]
decToBin x = reverse $ decToBin' x
    where
        decToBin' 0 = []
        decToBin' y = let (a,b) = quotRem y 2 in [b] ++ decToBin' a
binToDec ::  [Integer] -> Integer
binToDec xs = foldl (+) 0 $ map (\(x,y) -> x*(2^y) ) $reverse $ zip (reverse xs) [0..]

bitwise f x y = zipWith f x y

lenBin :: Integer -> Integer
lenBin x= length$ decToBin x

xor :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
xor x y  | x == y = 0
         | x /= y = 1
         | otherwise = error "Impossible"

bitwiseXOR :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer    
bitwiseXOR a b | (lenBin a) > (lenBin b) = binToDec $ bitwise xor ((replicate ((lenBin a) - (lenBin b)) 0)++(decToBin b)) (decToBin a)
               | (lenBin a) < (lenBin b) = binToDec $ bitwise xor ((replicate ((lenBin b) - (lenBin a)) 0)++(decToBin a)) (decToBin b)
               | otherwise =binToDec $ bitwise xor (decToBin b) (decToBin a)

decyph :: [char] -> [char]
decyph key = map chr $ map (\(x,y)-> bitwiseXOR x (ord y) ) $ zip numbers $ cycle key

brute :: [([Char],[Char])]
brute = [(n,k)|k<- (sequence $ replicate 3 ['a'..'z']) ,n <- decyph k, "the" `isInfixOf` n]

numbers :: [Integer]
numbers = [79,59,12,2,79,35,8...]
```

The problem is that when I can't run `decyph` because the tuples it is producing only contain one character in the first part and the key in the second rather than the entire decrypted text with the key used. How can I fix this?

PS: Is it reasonable to assume the text will contain string "the"?

Comment: Could you add the types of the functions, for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decyph key` returns the deciphered text as a `[Char]`. With the syntax

```
n <- decyph k
```

in your list comprehension, `n` will be of type `Char` and be assigned the individual characters of the deciphered text, but what you want here is that it is assigned the full result of `decyph` so make it

```
let n = decyph k
```

Finally, check the type of `elem`:

```
> :t elem
elem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

with the type of `n` being `[Char]`, the first argument must be `Char`, but you have another string there. If you wish to work with `elems`, you could split up the deciphered text in words:

```
"the" `elem` words n
```

This will compile here then.

> PS: Is it reasonable to assume the
>   text will contain string "the"?

It is most certainly a common English word, but the text could possibly be all-uppercase or `the` might only appear as `The` at the beginning of a sentence.